# TensorCirucit c.draw() NameError

Tags: google-colaboratory, draw, qiskit

I want to plot a circuit build with TensorCircuit using the `draw` method.

I am working on Google Colab and have pip installed qiskit.
Yet i get `NameError: name 'QuantumCircuit'` is not defined.
I have also tried  `from qiskit import QuantumCircuit` but still i get the same error.

Executing the code on another JuypterHub works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install qiskit
pip install pylatexenc

import numpy as np
from qiskit import *
```

Once you are done with above code you have to restart your runtime so that installed library come into force into your colab environment.

For restarting runtime:

```
Click on Runtime
Select Restart runtime 
Select Run all
```

This help you to rectify your problem.